# Pulp optimization not repeated permutation combination

Tags: python, math, optimization, pulp

I am working on a optimization problem where my objective is maximize profit when two products pair are sold but the constraint is, the products in the pair should not repeat.

[image]

I am using Pulp to optimize the solution but the code is inefficient and goes on an infinite loop.

```py
file = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')

main_product_1 = list(file['Product ID'].unique())
main_product_2 = list(file['Product ID 2'].unique())

file.set_index(['Product ID', 'Product ID 2'], inplace=True)
file = file['Profit']

# Target Variable
combine = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("combine",
                                ((product_1, product_2) for product_1 in main_product_1 for
                                 product_2 in main_product_2 if product_1 != product_2),
                                cat='Binary')

# Initializing the model

model = pulp.LpProblem("prof_max", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Objective Function optimization
model += pulp.lpSum(
        [combine[product_1, product_2] * file.loc[(product_1, product_2)] for product_1 in
         main_product_1 for product_2 in main_product_2 if product_1 != product_2])

# Constraints for optimization
for area in set_plant:
  model += pulp.lpSum([combine[area, other] for other in main_product_1 if area != other]
                      + [combine[other, area] for other in main_product_2 if area != other]) == 1

model.solve()
print(pulp.LpStatus[model.status])

# Check
set_index = set(file.index)
set_expected = set(
        [(product_1, product_2) for product_1 in main_product_1 for product_2 in main_product_2 if
         product_1 != product_2])
len(set_expected - set_index)
```

The problem is that the code goes into infinite loop and I am not getting any results, is there a more optimized way of running this appraoch?

Comment: Are you talking about the permutation or the combination of product IDs? Can (1000, 1001) and (1001, 1000) both be in the result, or only one?

Comment: if we have a pair which already has 1000 and 1001, they can't be repeated as product ID or product ID 1 in any other pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding a very, very large number of integer variables, and Integer Linear Programming is an extremely hard and inefficient problem to solve. However, there might be some additional improvements you can have.

Consider instead the following construct:

1. If you have `M` instances of product 1 and `N` instances of product 2, then you have `MN` binary variables `x_mn`;
2. Each of these variables contributes `P` to the objective function if `x_mn` is 1;
3. You say in your constraints that `x_mn + x_nm == 1`, but really, it should be `x_mn + x_nm <= 1`. Otherwise, you say that you *MUST* have each combination in your list. This will likely lead to infeasable solutions;
4. If you're considering combinations and not permutations (i.e. [1000, 1001] and [1001, 1000] are the same, then that means `M = N` and you can remove just about half of your variables only to have `M^2 / 2` left. (If you see the value space as an MxM square, you only accept about a triangle, since the other triangle is equivalent;
5. You actually don't need any constraints if you limit the variable space like mentioned in the point above; If `x_nm` does not exist, then `x_mn <= 1` is obvious for a binary variable.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp

file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
file = file[file['Product ID'] < file['Product ID 2']]
file.set_index(['Product ID', 'Product ID 2'], inplace=True)
file = file['Profit']

combinations = file.index
individual_products = set()

for product_1, product_2 in combinations:
individual_products.add(product_1)
individual_products.add(product_2)

# Target Variable
combine = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("combine", combinations, cat='Binary')

# Initializing the model

model = pulp.LpProblem("prof_max", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Objective Function optimization
model += pulp.lpSum([combine[i] for i in file.index] * file)

# All individual products can only be used once
for product in individual_products:
matching_combinations = combinations[(combinations.to_frame() == product).any(axis=1)]
model += pulp.lpSum([combine[i] for i in matching_combinations]) <= 1

model.solve()
print(pulp.LpStatus[model.status])
print([v for v in model.variables() if v.varValue > 0])
```

By these changes, without changing the problem or the inherent implementation, you have essentially removed 75% of your constraints.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I am getting an error of 'Too many indexer' while using the line "" # Objective Function optimization - note again the <
model += pulp.lpSum(
        [combine[product_1, product_2] * file.loc[(product_1, product_2)] for product_1 in
         main_products for product_2 in main_products if product_1 < product_2]) ""

Comment: File doesn't have the required structure, it still contains many combinations of (A, B) and (B, A). Are you able to clean that up?

Comment: I was able to clean it with "file = file[~file[['Product ID', 'Product ID 1']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
" Still facing the issue. 'Too many indexers"

Comment: What if you use `file.loc[product_1, product_2]` without `()`-brackets?

Comment: Use print statements to find the problem, is it `file` or `combine`? One of `print(combine[product_1, product_2])` and `print(file.loc[product_1, product_2])` should give an error. I am beginning to think you need to use `combine[(product_1, product_2)]`

Comment: for product_1 in main_products:
    for product_2 in main_products:
        print(combine[product_1, product_2])

gave me KeyError: ('1053', '1053')

for product_1 in main_products:
    for product_2 in main_products:
        print(file.loc[product_1, product_2])

Gave me 'too many indexer'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220031/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-rishab-oberoi).